# how to add body and app bar same gradient in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to add same LinearGradient to appbar and body. But two gradient color.

I want to gradient without any different.

```
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: CustomGradient.appBarGradient //body gradient
  ),
  child:Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  backgroundColor: Palette.transparent,
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
    centerTitle: true,
    title: //text,
    flexibleSpace: Container( //appBar gradient
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             gradient: CustomGradient.appBarGradient
      ),
    ),
  ),
  body:
```

Comment: Is making your `appBar` transparent and extend the body behind it an option ? If yes use `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true` in your `Scaffold` and `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, elevation: 0` in your `appBar`. Else you could either stack your `appBar` with your content in the body, or create 2 different gradients, the first one with the same ending color as the starting color of the 2nd one.

Comment: @Yann39 background color is already transparent. I forgot to edit on stackoverflow

Comment: Your `Scaffold` background color is transparent, not your `appBar`.

Comment: my problem is `container` gradient and appBar gradient doesn't match.

Comment: But you don't need 2 gradients, I will try an answer with an example

Comment: can we usesame gradient in appBar and body? If it is impossible, we can remove appBar and design appBar inside the `body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make your `appBar` transparent.

Example :

```dart
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: CustomGradient.appBarGradient,
  ),
  child: Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: 0.0,
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text("test"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) Text("Hello world", textScaleFactor: 4),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

If you want your body content to be extended behind the `appBar`, use `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true` in your `Scaffold` (and keep `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, elevation: 0` in your `appBar`).

You have other solutions like stacking your `appBar` with your content in the body, or creating 2 different gradients for your `appBar` and your `body`, the first one with the same ending color as the starting color of the 2nd one.

Answer (score 2):

My application also had this issue. Because my appbar and body container has same linear gradient color, Firstly I added gradient colors separately but it didn't display correctly, then I removed appbar color and make it transparent. From this way I resolved my issue.

```
return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar:
            true, // Set this to true to extend the body behind the app bar
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
          ),
          leading: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: [
                Color(0xFFFAFEFF),
                Color(0xFFABFFDC),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```